# api-ms-win-core-heap-l2-1-0.dll missing on windows server 2012 R2

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, onnxruntime

The application is developed with VC++2022 on Windows-11 using onnxruntime-win-x64-1.14.1.
When the application is deployed on Windows Server 2012 R2, it runs with error:

```
api-ms-win-core-heap-l2-1-0.dll missing
```

[image]

Running dependency walker on Windows Server 2012 R2 shows:
[image]

Here is another topic about this issue:
[error api-ms-win-core-heap-l2-1-0.dll is missing from your computer when saving pdf in Acrobat Reader RC](https://community.adobe.com/t5/acrobat-reader-discussions/error-api-ms-win-core-heap-l2-1-0-dll-is-missing-from-your-computer-when-saving-pdf-in-acrobat/td-p/8918448)

How to fix this problem?

---

Here is the VS settings:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you installed the appropriate runtime for the exe that you built? When you built the exe, are you targeting the right OS version?

Comment: this is *KernelBase.dll* , but on win7/8 probably this name unknown. you need build with another import lib simply. *dependency walker* - broken tool. it not show correct info. @DavidHeffernan - *api-ms-win-..* - this is not runtime but built in windows modules

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/apiindex/windows-apisets - you probably build with OneCore.lib when need use "classic" libs

Comment: @RbMm the runtime calls the windows api

Comment: @DavidHeffernan of course. but this problem can not be fixed by installing some runtime package. or runtime or application direct build to api set which not supported on this win8. so need use another runtime or another import lib

Comment: @RbMm If the runtime for the exe that was built does not support the target OS, then the answer to my first question is no, and the second question is pertinent. The point is that the asker needs to work out what they are targeting.

Comment: Link to kernel32.lib instead of mincore.lib or onecore.lib.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Where can I set the targeting OS in VS-2022?

Comment: @HansPassant I use default VS settings, in Linker/Command Line I can see it is using 'kernel32.lib'

Comment: "Windows SDK Version = 10.0 (latest installed version)" will default to programs that require whatever version Windows corresponds to the SDK you installed. If you want to run on Windows 8 / Server 2012, you need to set `NTDDI_VERSION` to `NTDDI_WIN8`. Ideally, you use a Windows 8 SDK instead of trying to get a Windows 8-compatible subset of a Windows 10 SDK.

Comment: @RaymondChen Where can I set `NTDDI_VERSION` to `NTDDI_WIN8` in VS2022? Ideally I want my app run on Server 2012 and Server 2019+.

Comment: `#define NTDDI_VERSION NTDDI_WIN8` anywhere before including `windows.h`. [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/using-the-windows-headers?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

Comment: @RaymondChen Your above solution works. But onnxruntime.dll still depends on api-ms-win-core-heap-l2-1-0.dll, so I guess I have to build onnxruntime.dll from source.

Comment: BTW, I use `#define NTDDI_VERSION NTDDI_WINBLUE` instead of `#define NTDDI_VERSION NTDDI_WIN8` since Server 2012 is 8.1 based.